# Connection refused while using curl command for Elasticsearch

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I am trying to set up a ES index.

I installed elasticsearch using :

```
brew update
brew install elasticsearch
```

Then I ran

```
curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/analytics1' -d '{"settings" : {"index" :{"number_of_shards" : 1,"number_of_replicas" : 1}},"mappings": {"trip-details": {"properties": {"shipment_vehicleNum": {"index": "not_analyzed", "type": "string"},}
```

It gave me this error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9200: Connection refused
```

I looked up a couple of stackoverflow answers for this error and some suggested changing the network.host in elasticsearch.yml to 0.0.0.0
I did this and still I am getting the same error.

What am I missing?
Should i Install Elasticsearch manually(Using Java)?

Comment: it's not clear from your question whether you started elasticsearch at all or not

Comment: Yeah I did not start my Elasticsearch service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you did not start your service. Check your brew services list

```
brew services list
```

If there is an elasticsearch service and stopped. Start it with following command:

```
brew services start elasticsearch
```

Thats it.